# MongoDB - pymongo.errors.DocumentTooLarge Error

Tags: python, mongodb, gridfs

I have a REST interface which POSTs data to MongoDB. The data is basically file system structure as a nested JSON structure where each level in the JSON has a key "children". This children contains the sub-directories if it's a folder or if it's a file, then it contains the contents of the file as an array of Strings. This data is later used by another Java-based application. An example of what the JSON data looks like is:

```
{
    'name': 'sys',
    'type': 'system',
    'path': 'sys',
    'children': [{
        'name': 'folder1',
        'type': 'folder',
        'path': 'sys/folder1',
        'children': [{
            'name': 'folder2',
            'type': 'folder',
            'path': 'sys/folder1/folder2',
            'children': [{
                'name': 'textf1.txt',
                'type': 'file',
                'path': 'sys/folder1/folder2/textf1.txt',
                'children': ['abc', 'def']
            }, {
                'name': 'textf2.txt',
                'type': 'file',
                'path': 'sys/folder1/folder2/textf2.txt',
                'children': ['a', 'b', 'c']
            }]
        }, {
            'name': 'text1.txt',
            'type': 'file',
            'path': 'sys/folder1/text1.txt',
            'children': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
        }]
    }],
    '_id': ObjectId('5d1211ead866fc19ccdf0c77')
}
```

The way I am parsing the file system structures is:

```
def path_to_dict(path, child=False):
    d = {'name': os.path.basename(path)}
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        if not child:
            d['type'] = "system"
        else:
            d['type'] = "folder"
        d['path'] = os.path.relpath(path)
        d['children'] = [path_to_dict(os.path.join(path, x),
            child=True) for x in os.listdir\(path)]
    else:
        if not child:
            d['type'] = "system"
        else:
            d['type'] = "file"
        d['path'] = os.path.relpath(path)
        with open(path, 'r', encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore') as myfile:
            content = myfile.read().splitlines()
        d['children'] = content
    return d
```

Now all of the file systems I parsed worked successfully except for one system which gave the error:
`pymongo.errors.DocumentTooLarge: BSON document too large (74101706 bytes) - the connected server supports BSON document sizes up to 16793598 bytes.`

I understand that there is a limitation of 16MB limit on document size and many have suggested the use of GridFS to break up the file. My problem is there is not one single file which contributes to such a large document size but multiple small documents.

My server POST endpoint is as follows:

```
def post(self, collection_name):
        user = mongo.db[collection_name]  
        client_request = request.get_json(force=True)
        user.insert(client_request)
```

What can be a solution to this problem? Is GridFS useful in a scenario like this?

EDIT: The file system structure which fails has multiple sub-folders containing C files, contents of which are treated as Strings and are stored as an array of Strings in the nested JSON.